# How can I get rid of the discoloration on this tub?

Tags: bathroom, bathtub

I would not like to resurface/reglaze at this time, but it just looks dingy. I made some progress, but it's still bothering me.

[image]

Comment: Scouring powder and elbow grease.

Comment: You made progress... and then stopped making progress? I don't see the problem other than lack of ambition. If you're asking for _better_ ways, at least tell us what you've tried and the outcome.

Comment: @ Isherwood,  Do you work at insulting new contributors, or does it come naturally?

Comment: Plastic? Uh, next question, please.

Answer (score 1):

I have had luck with [Magic eraser](https://www.google.com/search?q=magic%20eraser.&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS987US987&oq=magic%20eraser.&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l7j0i390i650l2.1403405076j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), having encountered some pretty nasty tubs in properties I purchased.

Ok course it depends on a few of factors:

What caused the stains.

What is the tub made of.

Is the surface worn already.

From the picture it looks like the tub just lacked normal cleaning over time.

Comment: Magic Erasers are basically just abrasive.  If a good bleaching doesn't do any good, taking a page from auto body work would be a lot less work than scrubbing with a Magic Eraser.  Buy/borrow/rent a DA polisher and get some 3000-5000 grit wetsanding pads and some speed glaze.